# NLog - System.MethodAccessException only in VMWare Horizon View client

Tags: c#, vmware, nlog

I updated my C# WPF application to use latest versions of NLog and NLog.Extensions.Logging.

It works everywhere except in this VMWare Horizons client where it crashes with this error:

```
    $exception  {"Attempt by method 'NLog.Extensions.Logging.NLogLoggerProvider..ctor(NLog.Extensions.Logging.NLogProviderOptions, NLog.LogFactory)' to access method 'NLog.LogManager.get_LogFactory()' failed."}  System.MethodAccessException
```

This project is currently using NLog v4.5.11 and
NLog.Extensions.Logging v1.4

A previous version of my application which uses NLog v.4.4.12 and 
NLog.Extensions.Logging v1.0 worked in this VM so i am trying to fall back to that.  Then i'll work my way up the versions of these libraries.

More to follow soon...  meanwhile, any insight into what might be causing this would be very welcome.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
            var Logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();

            loggerFactory.AddNLog();


            Logger.LogDebug($"============{Environment.NewLine}");

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your deployment. Your application is not using NLog ver. 4.5 (But some older version).

LogFactory-property became public with this: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2316

Maybe you have old NLog registered in Windows GAC ? (Global Assembly Cache)

Maybe try writing the `typeof(NLog.LogFactory).Assembly`-location using Console.WriteLine.

Comment: Rolf, 
Thanks. You are right!  i had activated the internallog and it dod show that nlog was being loaded from the GAC.
I even tried removing it using GacUtil.exe but it would not remove it because another application had a reference to it. 

How do i work around this?

Regards
Habib

Comment: Nlog in GAC:  NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c
My application uses nlog 4.5 but it too has the same version and publicKeyToken.

Because the version and PublicKeyTokens are identical, could the GAC take precedence over the one in the install folder?

i used to gacutil.exe /i <path to nlog.dll> to import the new version to the GAC.  that worked.  The previous application also works without issue.

Can i force the application to use the dll in the install folder, ignoring the GAC?

Comment: Think the only way to avoid the GAC is to perform ILMerge, or use NetCore.

Comment: Just delete the dll, the path to which will show 'typeof(NLog.LogFactory).Assembly.Location'. 
This GAC issue is actually for Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54557849/8081796

This issue is actual for Windows 8.

Get path to used NLog.dll:

```
typeof(NLog.LogFactory).Assembly.Location
```

If the path leads somewhere in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL` then just delete this file

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stepan.
As I recall, it is not easy to delete a file from the GAC. And from what I have learned, not a good practice because it could break another application that depended on it.

Windows installer maintains a reference count of items in GAC, increasing the count with each install, reducing with each uninstall.  If the count goes to 0, the dll is also removed from the GAC.

I uninstalled the application that put Nlog in the GAC.  (It was another application that I had written long ago.)  Then i modified the installer for that old app, ensured that it did not put it back in the GAC and re-installed it.  And everything was well again.